# SLURM job dependency by job name not job id

Tags: slurm

The format for job dependencies in the documentation is as follows:

`sbatch --dependency=<type:job_id[:job_id][,type:job_id[:job_id]]> ...`

Is it possible to make a job dependency using job name instead of job ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slurm does not seem to handle that, but a workaround, that would work in the command line (not in a `#SBATCH` directive in a script), would be:

```
sbatch --dependency=$(squeue --noheader --format %i --name <JOB_NAME>) ...
```